# Python Django как вывести аудио файл из стандартной базы данных django на страниу html?

Tags: python, html, база-данных, django, аудио

Python Django как вывести аудио файл из стандартной базы данных django на страницу html ? При том это он должен находится в теги audio и полностью функционировать. Сам аудио файл находится в поле FileField таблицы.

Comment: рендерите страницу и туда вставляете ссылку на ваш файл

Comment: Мне нужно обязательно вытаскивать файл из бд. Как например с текстом

Comment: `FileField` не сохраняет файл в базу, вы должны прописать `upload_to`, а уже конкретно в `html` можно прописать путь в файлу который сохранен на хосте